# Csrfguard behind a reverse proxy

Tags: java, web-applications, csrf, reverse-proxy

I have successfully installed [CsrfGuard](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_CSRFGuard_Project) on my webapp but when tested on preprod behind the reverse proxy things got bad.
CsrfGuard's javascript isValidDomain does not consider my domain as a valid one : CsrfGuard JavaScriptServlet returns the unproxied domain...

This is the javascript code:

```
if(isValidDomain(document.domain, "myRealDomain")) { … }
```

`isValidDomain` is just a string comparison method, the thing is : CsrfGuard JavaScriptServlet returns "myRealDomain" and the javascript code "document.domain" returns "myProxiedDomain" : string comparison fails!

I don't know what to do at that point and I would appreciate directions! I believe that some have met the problem before, reverse proxies seem quite common.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CsrfGuard, but can you extend `JavaScriptServlet` and provide a configurable value for `myRealDomain`?

Comment: Well, that is one of the solutions, however the JavaScriptServlet is final, I would need to make my own version of the lib to do this...

Comment: May need to override the isValidDomain method to be reverse-proxy aware then.  Seems like a limitation of the framework, good luck.

Answer (score 6):

you could configure your proxy to add the headers `X-Forwarded-By`, `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto`.

Your server behind the proxy could use these headers to reconstruct the original request (as performed on the proxy).

This way csrfguard servlet will use the correct domain to generate the script.

Configuration is of course different per proxy/application server, but here is an example for Nginx in combination with Tomcat:

example proxy config (Nginx):

```
### proxy headers ###
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-By          $server_addr:$server_port;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
```

example application server (tomcat / [RemoteIpValve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html)):

```
<Valve
    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
    internalProxies="trusted-ip-here"
    remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
    proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
    protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"
   />
```

Comment: In my case I needed additional `httpServerPort` and `trustedProxies` [params](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html) to get my Tomcat app proxy aware.

Answer (score 3):

We had similar issues with csrfguard and found that our proxy server was returning wrong 'Referer' URL. In addition to it we werer using SSL whichadded additional issues. We found that once the connection was made - it was done with 'domain.tld' instead of 'domain.tld:443' which was expected by csrfguard.

```
 Referer domain https://localhost/shop/pages/main.jsf
 does not match request domain: https://localhost:443/shop/JS/csrfguard.js
```

We fixed this by adding this to apache httpd config:

```
Header edit Referer "(^http(s?)://([\w]+\.){1}([\w]+\.?)+)(.*)$" "$1:443$5"
RequestHeader edit Referer "(^http(s?)://([\w]+\.){1}([\w]+\.?)+)(.*)$" "$1:443$5"
```

Since all requests were coming from https, we fixed port presence in the URI by this.
I believe your case can be fixed by the same way or by setting 'Referer' header to some pre-defined name. (But it may be a security issue here, cause all requests will be coming from 'proper' domain)

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue where running csrfguard-3.1 behind a reverse proxy and load balancer with SSL offloading caused the JavaScriptServlet to return a 404. The csrf log stated

"Referer domain https://********* does not match the request domain http://**********"

I had to set the

```
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.refererMatchDomain=false
```

to get it to work.

Comment: This solution also worked for me - I had the same problem when implementing CSRFGuard on Azure Linux WebApps, with CloudFlare.